# How to interpret this bit shift

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have the following bit shift:

`1011 & (~0 << 2)`

How do I work out the answer for this? In particular I am confused about what ~0 << 2 means - I know that the << operator is a bit shift, and that ~ represents 'not'.

What I have read is that ~0 is a sequence of 1s - but how is that true, and how many 1s are there??

Comment: `~0 = 1`, but it is inconsistent with `1011`, because, `~0 << 2 = 0` (overflow), do you know with how many bits you are working?

Comment: @CamiloR this is wrong. ~0 != 1. ~0 = 111...111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, an int is a 32-bit/4-byte value. So `~0` = `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`

In your case it really doesn't matter.

You want to solve `1011 & (~0 << 2)`

Let's go through your example in steps.

First thing that happens is the parenthesis:

```
(~0 << 2)
```

This is the bits 1111 shifted left by two bits. When a lift shift occurs the new added bits are 0s. Therefore `(~0 << 2)` equals:

```
(1111 << 2) = 1100
```

Finally you just need to do a bitwise and between `1011` and `1100` which ends up as

```
1000 = 8
```

Comment: Ok, I guess my misunderstanding is with ~0 being a series of 1s - why is this the case?

Comment: 0 int in bits is 0000, therefore the inverse of 0 aka ~0 is simply the inverse of all the bits, or 1111